# Confused about iCloud and iCloud Drive syncing to iOS and MacOS apps

Tags: icloud

A previous post describes my situation perfectly but it has not been fully answered almost 2 years later. Here is the post: [Confused about iCloud and iCloud Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425506/confused-about-icloud-and-icloud-drive/465529#465529)

I believe that ios and MacOS apps syncing to iCloud Drive is what's causing my iCloud Drive to state I'm using 90 GB when I can only account for 50 GB actually stored in my iCloud Drive. Why would Apple not allow me to inspect the full contents of my iCloud Drive? Current state I'm not able to manage the storage because I'm unable to see how much space each app is taking up in my iCloud Drive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’ve had great luck making screen shots and working with Apple support. They poked into engineering and found some things for me to change to make things make sense. Have you tried that or can you edit this with specific images and details for us to have a change to guess how you’re using storage?

Comment: My issue is that I see my iCloudDrive is using 90 GB but I can only account for 52 GB. I have a post live in Apple communities but I may try reaching out to Apple Support directly.

Comment: On the last screenshot, tap on „Manage Storage“ to see a usage breakdown by app.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of what I see when I tap 'manage storage' if I tap on Downloads, Documents or Desktop it will state "--" in the spot that's supposed to give the amount of data used and it shows the same exact files I see in my screenshot from my iCloud Drive from my Macbook.

Comment: On your Mac, click "Manage" (in that screenshot) and a new screen will come up. iCloud Drive is a subcategory of general "Documents" storage. When you bring up that Manage list you should see iCloud Drive of 50GB and then other applications taking up the rest of the storage. If you only see "iCloud Drive" there and it's 90GB, then give Apple a call for sure. https://i.imgur.com/SgEJNiz.png

Comment: Just added a screenshot, I appreciate all the help from everyone. I'll call Apple.

Comment: Update: I just got off the phone with an Apple senior advisor and was screen sharing my issue with them, they've never seen this issue before and they are investigating / possibly escalating the issue further up their system.